# Show RGB565 raw data with UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

I would like to save RGB565 raw image data to UIImage. Can this be done, or do I have to convert first to RGB888?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bit map context, do the conversion yourself in code, then create an image from the context. That's your only option. That said, you may be able to find an open source library that will do it, but I doubt it.